# Difference of interfaces in netstat -i and netstat -i 1 1 command

Tags: solaris, network-interface, netstat

Result of the `netstat -i` command in Solaris:

```
# netstat -i
Name  Mtu  Net/Dest      Address        Ipkts  Ierrs Opkts  Oerrs Collis Queue
lo0   8232 loopback      localhost      179    0     179    0     0      0
e1000g0 1500 solaris10     solaris10      38916  0     1301   0     0      0
e1000g1 1500 10.0.0.0      10.0.3.242     34284  0     20     0     0      0
```

Result of `netstat -i 1 1` command in Solaris:

```
# netstat -i 1 1
    input   e1000g    output       input  (Total)    output
packets errs  packets errs  colls  packets errs  packets errs  colls
40117   0     1334    0     0      75747   0     1533    0     0
```

My question is:

- Why `netstat -i 1 1` lists only one interface, that is `e1000g` and not two interfaces like I got in `netstat -i` command, that is `e1000g0` and `e1000g1`.?
- What I should do if I want to get multiple interfaces in `netstat -i 1 1` command.?

Comment: Yeah True @muru.  Let me update the question. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the e1000g1 interface is fully configured?  I believe that netstat -i will only show output for configured interfaces for the host (in your case named "solaris10."  You may also want to use -I to specify the interface you want to monitor.

The initial entry would also be the summary/historical value. You'll have to specify something other than "1" for the 2nd "1" to see more than just 1 iteration.

You may want to look at:
  `pfexec dladm show-dev`

Comment: I appreciate your answer , But I have to use `netstat -i 1 2` in my case as i want to monitor bandwidth of the network (packets and KB sent and received per second). also, i can not run the script `netstat -i 1` as the script should return and not run forever. I don't know what "fully configured" mean here.!?. and also `netstat -I e1000g0 1 2` and `netstat -I e1000g1 1 2` gives me same result. there should be some difference  right.?? Can you please suggest some answer to the questions i have asked in the post. Thanks..